# Рандомная выборка картинок по scr без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, canvas, изображения

На странице должен быть массив картинок с разными src. В данному случае scr рандомная, но одна для каждой загрузки страницы. Такое можно обойти с изображениями?

```
var tree1 = new Image(); 
var tree2 = new Image(); 
var tree3 = new Image(); 
var tree4 = new Image(); 

tree1.src = "tree1.png";
tree2.src = "tree2.png";
tree3.src = "tree3.png";
tree4.src = "tree4.png";

var masTree=[tree1, tree2, tree3, tree4];
var randTree=Math.floor(Math.random()*masTree.length);

ctx.drawImage(masTree[randTree],10, 10, 10, 10);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/02gv1zcL/ (это более ранняя версия кода с таким же результатом, код выше на jsfiddle не запускается http://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/9xhatjdv/, хотя с локалки работает)

Comment: Во-первых у вас переменная `tree` не объявлена, о чем говорит ошибка в консоли, во-вторых - путь к картинкам локальный, а вы пытаетесь их загрузить на стороннем сайте, отсюда и проблемы

Comment: @ThisMan, спасибо, лишнее удалила, ссылка обновленная. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - не знаете, что это?

Comment: это значит что не удалось найти картинки по данному пути

Comment: остальные картинки у вас загружаются

Comment: @ThisMan спасибо, адрес заменила. в console ошибок нет.  Но не запускается...

Answer (score 3):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы используете картинку ***до*** ее загрузки, которая выполняется *асинхронно*.

Объясняю на упрощенном примере:

```
var tree = new Image();
tree.src = "tree.png";
ctx.drawImage(tree,10, 10, 10, 10);
```

В этом примере во время вызова `ctx.drawImage` картинка `tree` ***недоступна***, т.к. она еще не успела загрузиться. Загрузка внешних ресурсов всегда занимает определенное время: доли секунды, а иногда и секунды, в зависимости от скорости соединения. Конечно, на локальном сервере загрузка может быть мгновенной, поэтому там данный пример может работать (хотя и не всегда). Но в "реальной жизни" картинка недоступна сразу после присваивания `src`.

Как это решить? Использовать картинку только после полной загрузки. Для этого нужно назначить обработчик для события `load` картинки и перенести вызов `ctx.drawImage` внутрь этого обработчика. В вашем случае это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
tree1.src = "tree1.png";
tree2.src = "tree2.png";
tree3.src = "tree3.png";
tree4.src = "tree4.png";
var masTree=[tree1, tree2, tree3, tree4];
var randTree=Math.floor(Math.random()*masTree.length);

masTree[randTree].addEventListener('load', function() {
    ctx.drawImage(masTree[randTree], 10, 10, 10, 10); 
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/L9bmyjcr/ наконец получилось залить на jsfiddle К сожалению не работает с добавление события load https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/porb251q/

Comment: Что ж вы делаете то? Зачем вы ставите обработчик события внутри цикла, да еще и внутри рекурсивной функции? В вашем случае обработчик должен ставиться всего **один** раз, желательно сразу после после присваивания `src`. У вас там кстати есть еще один обработчик - для `tree`. Вам нужно объединить его с обработчиком `masTree[randTree]`. Это можно сделать вложив один обработчик в другой: `tree.onload = function() {masTree[randTree].onload = draw;});`. Но лучше всего для этого использовать [промисы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Comment: Да, и раз уж вы там используете нотацию `onload` для `tree`, то и для `masTree[randTree]` тоже используйте ее, а не `addEventListener`.

Comment: тут конструкция такая, что, наверное, вашим методом не поставишь обработчик. http://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/ugyb1fd0/ Но спасибо за участие, буду изучать промисы. Тут и вправду нужна перезагрузка, только асинхронная. Может, такая технология еще появится и разовьется.